# powerflow corrupts xls mail-attachment?

Tags: attachment, power-automate

I have a simple flow that creates a mail and attaches an Excel File.
The Flow is triggered when a file is beeing created in that Sharepoint folder. So the triggerfile is exactly the excel file that i would like to send as attachment.

Most of the times the file is fine but sometimes (on every 20th run or so?) the file is not complete, i.e. missing the last lines.
Any ideas?

This is a picture of my simple flow:

[image]

Comment: This might be happening because the flow trigger "when a file created" is fired before the file has finished uploading. I am not sure what is the working workaround for this. Try using "when a file is modified" trigger amd see if that work as expected for newly uploaded files. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks - Trigger "when file is modified" or "when file is created or updated" leave all to same results.
It seems like a timing issue, trigger is fired but file is not completely written yet - so the unfinished file is attached to my mails.  
I tried around with waits... When i use a 2 mins wait just after the trigger in the beginning of the flow it seems to work. After several tests no more uncomplete files anymore!!!

However, I dont really like this approach. A system could be slow once later on and the problem could come again?
So I am still open for better solutions? Any ideas?

Comment: Just from the top of my head: maybe you can keep checking file size every 2 minutes, until it stops growing. That could mean the upload has finished. Anyway, please share if you find a solid solution for this